# How to set a UISwitch state, and bring up view controller, press cancel, and have it turn switch off

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Here's an issue I've been having, and i haven't been able to find anything anywhere to solve my issue, basically what i have going on, is a create event scenario, and i have a UISwitch that is supposed to toggle on, in my CreateEventViewController and bring up a view controller for that setting, which is my SetCountdownViewController, which it does, but i want to have a cancel button in SetCountdownViewController, that dismisses SetCountdownViewController and toggles my UISwitch off, but so far I've come up with a handful of errors and bugs.

i looked up several tutorials and they all told me to use `someSwitch.on`
and `someSwitch.setOn([state, true/false], animated:[true/false])`

and both seem to work at first, no errors pop up, i can build and run, but when i go to test my functionality and press my cancel button, it gives me an error saying "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on the line that says "        countdownSetSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
"

as well as "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" inside my log.

i have a function that is supposed to reset it to false, but thats where the error is occuring, no matter how/where i put .setOn, or .on, it gives me this error, and it seems like these may be deprecated, but they are somehow functional for building/running until they are actually called.

`func resetCountdownSwitch(){
        countdownSetSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }`

thats my function.

i am calling it in my IBAction for my cancel button here.

```
@IBAction func countdownCancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    createEventVC.resetCountdownSwitch()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

any help would be great, if you need more information id be happy to give it, I'm fairly new to Swift, and iOS development as a whole so it may be a rookie mistake, but I'm stumped.

Comment: It's definitely not deprecated. Where are you calling this function? What viewController owns the switch and what state is it in when you call this?

Comment: I'm calling this function inside my cancel button's IBAction, CreateEventViewController owns the switch, and by default its set in the off position, but i have it set to bring up SetCountdownViewController when the state is changed. @Dare

Comment: Show us the methods where this happens. If you present SetCountdownViewController and try and change the state of CreateEventViewController, there's a real chance the instance has been deallocated already when you do this and you're calling a function with nil.

Comment: @Dare updated question, is that what you are looking for?
also as far as calling the function with nil, youd be on to something, i updated the question, but i am getting a fatal error for finding nilwhen unwrapping optional value

Comment: @Dare, i followed your answer, and as far as ive figured it out, it works. but im trying to bind the function to the cancel button, not every time i come back to the view controller, any advice?

Comment: You can post a notification with NSNotificationCenter and have CreateEventViewController listen for it. The trick, in your case, is that the switch and the cancel button do not exist at the same time. You need to find a way to preserve/access the state of SetCountdownViewController that you want to check for from CreateEventViewController. On CreateEventViewController you can also override dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: completion:) if you only want to check when SetCountdownViewController is being dismissed; Assuming CreateEventViewController is the one that presented it.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining a reference to a view controller after it is no longer visible (because another view controller has been presented) doesn't promise that the view controller and its subviews won't be deallocated. Check [this reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCHy.jpg) for an idea of how the view lifecycle works.

What you likely want to do is check for whatever state you need in the viewWillAppear method of CreateEventViewController and set the value of the switch there. There's no need to animate it since it will not yet be visible. If you really want to make the flip animated, add the code to check your state and configure the button in viewDidAppear instead.

Your crash is likely due to the fact that createEventVC's subviews no longer exist when you call resetCountdownSwitch() and when you call countdownSetSwitch.setOn, you are actually calling the function with nil.